# Fading in usercontrol causes a white flash

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using XAML to fade in a usercontrol on its Load event. And this causes a white flash before the opacity increment begins. Here is the XAML code.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="UserControl1"
    x:Name="UserControl"
    d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" Opacity="0">
        <UserControl.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UserControl.Opacity)"
                                         From="0"
                                         To="1"
                                         Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>  
            </EventTrigger>
        </UserControl.Triggers>
        <UserControl.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="406-bubble.jpg"/>
        </UserControl.Background>
</UserControl>
```

I have checked some previous answers with this regard, but the solutions mentioned on those threads doesn't seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you putting your `<Usercontrol>` inside a container that has a white background?  Cause that would flash white, because the Opacity is 0.

Comment: the issue seems not reproducible with the provided code.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware No the usercontrol is the root control.

Comment: @pushpraj so is this a hardware issue?? I need the animation to begin from black & fade-in. Atleast then white flash won't look as bad & annoying to the users.

Comment: @codeGEN, I can not be 100% sure for an hardware issue. Is is possible for you to post a working sample which can reproduce the issue? may I give a try on the same. possibilities includes some other elements which might affect/interfere the same.

Comment: @pushpraj The above code is a working sample. Did try with an image? If not pls replace the <ImageBrush ImageSource="406-bubble.jpg"/> with a high resolution image, then you might be able to see the issue.

Comment: I did try the same with some image I had, let me try with some high resolution images.

Comment: When I try this it first flashes in white & then the image fades-in, I think if you lower the duration you might be able to see it more clearly. I am showing this in a full-screen & white flash is hard on the eye.

Comment: @codeGEN, I did try the same using high resolution (7000+ px) image, but seems like I can not see the flash or any flicker. perhaps the processor/graphic card difference. as a suggestion try adding easing to the animation and see if that helps. here an re-write of your animation on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/GLM38AHv)